# If Var is certain Value omit the WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

Is it possible to omit the `WHERE` if a variable is a certain value? The following doesn't work and I am struggling to find an answer;

```
DECLARE @rMonth int, @rYear int, @sID int
SET @rMonth  = 0;
SET @rYear = 0;
SET @sID= 0;

SELECT 
    TCS.bStatus AS jStatus, TCS.ID, TCS.sID, TCS.insDate, TCS.statusLabel, TCS.cID
FROM 
    TCS
    CASE WHEN @rMonth > 0 THEN 
        WHERE month(insDate) = @rMonth AND year(insDate)  = @rYear 
END
```

Comment: If you have a large table and care about performance, you should ask another question.  The structure of your `where` (and the `where` statements in the answers) prevents the use of indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common scenario to include a clause conditionally

check this out:

```
WHERE 
     (@rMonth = 0  OR MONTH(insDate) = @rMonth)
AND  (@rYear = 0 OR YEAR(insDate) = @rYear)
AND  (@sID = 0 OR sID = @sID)
```

In above query and for each clause, right hand side of "OR" is applied only if left hand side is false.   Otherwise whole clause is considered as true and does not filter any row.
Hopefully,by using above trick any complex clause could be written in right side of "OR" rather than a simple equality comparision.

Comment: Interesting. I usually see that done with NULL, like `WHERE (@rMonth IS NULL OR MONTH(insDate) = @rMonth)`

Comment: @JohnSaunders You are right, passing those parameters as NULL sounds more standard. But he tries to consider 0 as Nothing, so thats his choice :)

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE
  (@rMonth <= 0)
  OR
  (month(insDate) = @rMonth AND year(insDate) = @rYear)
```

Comment: Thank you @GSerg. please read my comment in the above answer. I need to retrieve all records When rMonth = 0.

Comment: This will retrieve all records when rMonth = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Another two options to achieve the same result:

one - using `CASE` statement like you wanted initially:

```
WHERE MONTH(insDate) = CASE WHEN @rMonth > 0 THEN @rMonth ELSE MONTH(insDate) END
AND YEAR(insDate) = CASE WHEN @rYear > 0 THEN @rYear ELSE YEAR(insDate) END
AND sID = CASE WHEN @sID > 0 THEN @sID ELSE sID END
```

and another - using `ISNULL` and `NULLIF` functions:

```
WHERE MONTH(insDate) = ISNULL(NULLIF(@rMonth, 0), MONTH(insDate))
AND YEAR(insDate) = ISNULL(NULLIF(@rYear, 0), YEAR(insDate))
AND sID = ISNULL(NULLIF(@sID, 0), sID)
```